# Python - Scipy Multivariate normal generalized to 1 dimension

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

When running `y = multivariate_normal(np.zeros(d), np.eye(d)).rvs()` we obtain a sample of dimension `(d, )`. However, when `d=1` we obtain a scalar, which makes sense since it's 1 dimensional. Unfortunately, I have some piece of code that must work for any number of dimensions, including `d=1`, and basically takes the dot product of a `d` dimensional vector `x` with `y`. This breaks for `d=1`. How can I fix it?

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal as MVN

def mwe_function(d, x):
    """Minimal Working Example"""
    y = MVN(np.zeros(d), np.eye(d)).rvs()
    return x @ y

mwe_function(2, np.ones(2))  # This works
mwe_function(1, np.ones(1))  # This doesn't
```

IMPORTANT: I want to avoid if statements. One could simply use `scipy.stats.norm` in that case, but I want to avoid if statements as they would slow down the code.

Comment: The only thing I could come up with was to do `np.array([y]).flatten()`

Comment: You can use something like [`np.atleast_1d`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.atleast_1d.html), i.e. `d = np.atleast_1d(d)` inside your function.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`np.reshape`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) to fix the shape of your sample. By using `-1` to specify the length of the first dimension, you will always get a 1-dimensional array and no scalar.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal as MVN

def mwe_function(d, x):
    """Minimal Working Example"""
    y = MVN(np.zeros(d), np.eye(d)).rvs().reshape([-1])
    return x @ y

v0 = mwe_function(2, np.ones(2))  # This works
print(v0)  # -0.5718013906409207
v1 = mwe_function(1, np.ones(1))  # This works as well :-)
print(v1)  # -0.20196038784485093
```

where `.reshape([-1])` does the job.

Personally, I prefer reshaping over using [`np.atleast_1d`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.atleast_1d.html), since the effect is directly visible - but in the end it is a matter of taste.

Comment: On NICE!! I kept on trying things like `.reshape(-1, 1)` but they would become 2D vectors, brilliant!

Comment: @Euler_Salter I'm glad I could help. If this answer solved your issue, please consider accepting it :-)